# python3 not able to create video using opencv 3 in linux14.04

Tags: python-3.x, camera, python-3.4, codec, opencv3.0

i have been trying python and opencv3 combo for video capture and manipulate

this is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break



cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but after running the code i am getting a output.avi file with duration:0 and moreover on playing it gives error: demultiplexing error
plz help me out

Comment: this is the link i followed for this program: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video

Comment: i must add that i am able to see the flipped video through web-cam without any problem